# EF Core - Include related entities using a generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

previously, back in EF Frameowrk days, the following method sufficed when needing the related entities to an entity.

```
private IQueryable<T> EntitySet(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var set = Context.Set<T>().Where(x => !x.IsDeleted);
        if (includes != null)
        {
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                set = set.Include(include);
            }                
        }
        return set;
    }
```

I'd call this method with something like `EntitySet(x => x.People, x => x.People.Meetings)`. However, ever since moving to EF core, I can no longer get the related data because I need to explicitly use `Include(x.People).ThenInclude(p.Meegings)`.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in EF core? Or were there so many changes in gather related data so that the above method is no longer applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost seems like you are attempting to add a filter to many queries of the same DbSet. Have you looked at Query Filters before in EF Core? It seems very similar to what you are trying to do. If you need to have a query should get all records instead of just active records, there is an option to ignore query filters at a by query basis.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters

Edit:
If you are looking to dynamically specify your includes still. You can do so with Strings in EF Core the same as was done in EF. However, the ability to use a lambda to access child objects may have gotten lost in conversion. https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/38083198/add-include-expressions-dynamically

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not really the same thing. QF can be used in injunction with `Include`. You'd use Query Filters if you want to say 'exclude all deleted tagged records'

Comment: Ability to use lambda is not lost. It pretty much mentioned in the post.

Comment: @GuruStron Please provide an example of how to do a lambda Include for a child object. Ali stated the intent not to do Include(<>).ThenInclude(<>). The only alternative in EFCore is a string of Include("Parent.Child").

Comment: You are still able to access children with lambda. As you said - with `ThenInclude`.

Comment: @GuruStron OP asked for alternatives to ThenInclude to allow the child includes specified to be kept dynamic.

Comment: Yep, still ability to use lambdas is not lost it was refactored. Yes, it can not  be used in this case, but again it is not lost.

Comment: @GuruStron It is not refactored. The EF solution allowed for string inputs as well as the EF Core logic. The EF ability to use lambdas to access child objects did not refactor into the use of strings because strings were already being used.